# How to use LIDT from inline assembly to load an interrupt vector table?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, osdev

I am trying to write a simple operating system using *GCC* that will allow me display text on the display that I type. I have an interrupt table in *C* that I need to load and want to be able to do that using inline assembly rather than an external assembly language module.

What I am looking for is a way to pass a *C* pointer into inline assembly.

The instruction I am attempting to inline that requires a memory operand is [*LIDT*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html):

> Loads the values in the source operand into the global descriptor table register (GDTR) or the interrupt descriptor table register (IDTR). The source operand specifies a 6-byte memory location that contains the base address (a linear address) and the limit (size of table in bytes) of the global descriptor table (GDT) or the interrupt descriptor table (IDT). If operand-size attribute is 32 bits, a 16-bit limit (lower 2 bytes of the 6-byte data operand) and a 32-bit base address (upper 4 bytes of the data operand) are loaded into the register. If the operand-size attribute is 16 bits, a 16-bit limit (lower 2 bytes) and a 24-bit base address (third, fourth, and fifth byte) are loaded. Here, the high-order byte of the operand is not used and the high-order byte of the base address in the GDTR or IDTR is filled with zeros.

Comment: I assume this is in protected mode and you are looking to use the `lidt` instruction to load the IDTR  from a memory location containing a 6 byte IDT record (It has the base address and the limit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't provide any code, and you don't say which *C* compiler but I'll assume *GCC* and a 32-bit kernel. This is an example of what you could do:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct idt_record
{
    uint16_t  limit;      /* Size of IDT array - 1 */
    uintptr_t base;       /* Pointer to IDT array  */
} __attribute__((packed));

void load_idt (struct idt_record *idt_r)
{
    __asm__ ("lidt %0" :: "m"(*idt_r));
}
```

This code uses inline assembly and passes the address of the *IDT* record into the extended inline template where it is used by the [*LIDT*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) instruction. We use the `m` [constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints). Had the parameter to the constraint been `(idt_r)` it would pass a memory reference to the pointer. We want a memory reference to the actual data so we de-reference it with `*` which is why I used `"m"(*idt_r)`.

You have to set `base` to point to your actual *IDT* array and `limit` would be the size of the *IDT* array minus 1. If you had shown us your data structures I wouldn't have to provide such a generic response. I don't know how you defined your *IDT* record structure so I used a quick and simple one for the example.

I'd probably provide `load_idt` function inside an include file and mark the function as `static inline`.

---

**Note**: If you are using a structure for the *IDT* record make sure you **pack** the structure similar to what I have done with `__attribute__((packed))` . If you don't pack it an additional 2 bytes will be added between the `limit` and `base` which will generate a corrupted *IDT* record.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I found a lot on how to do it online, but i really wanted to be able to do it from gcc.